Private Sub CommandButton1_Click() keep getting not defined error
I am a beginner to Excel VBA and trying to run the following code but keep receiving User-defined type not defined compile error. please help
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
    Dim fo As Folder
    Dim f As File
    Dim last_row As Integer
    last_row = Worksheets("Renommer Fichiers").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Set fo = fso.GetFolder(Worksheets("Renommer Fichiers").Cells(2, 5).Value)
    For Each f In fo.Files
        last_row = last_row + 1
        Worksheets("Renommer Fichiers").Cells(1, 1).Select
        MsgBox ("Voici la liste des fichiers")
    End Sub

I am trying to retrieve a list of files

Side note: change Integer to Long.
